ASP.NET web application with Windows Authentication - database sees machine user instead of web user
My web application connects to the database with this connection string:
<add name="ConnName" 
     connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=Yes;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

I also have:
<system.web>    
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    ...
</system.web>   

Everything works well on my local machine with Visual Studio. When deployed to the server, with Windows authentication enabled in IIS, I get this error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070542)

When I comment out the authentication and identity lines in the web.config, the website loads fine. But the database sees the user as the machine name, not the authenticated user.
Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this? Thanks.
I have tried setting Windows authentication under <system.webServer> instead:
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <authentication>
            <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
            <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
    </security>
</system.webServer>

But it doesn't seem to make a difference.
